# Merge Tables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to merge two data.frames in R so that the values in test_1 are overwritten if they exist in test_2

Every time I try and join/merge them I end up with a bunch of NAs.

I can't work out a simple logic for if.na then use test_2.  Is that what I'd need to do, or is there an easier way?

```
test_1 = structure(list(rn = c("Red", "Blue", 
                      "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Gold"
), X2022.08.01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.02 = c(0, 0, 0, 
                                                      0, 0, 0), X2022.08.03 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.04 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.05 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.08 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.09 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.10 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.12 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.16 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.18 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.22 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.24 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.26 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.29 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.30 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.31 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                6L), class = "data.frame")



test_2 = structure(list(rn = c("Blue", "Pink", 
                               "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Gold"
), X2022.08.01 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.03 = c(10, 10, 10, 
                                                      10, 10, 10), X2022.08.04 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.05 = c(10, 
                                                                                                                   10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.26 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the desired output would look like this:

```
test_output = structure(list(rn = c("Red", "Blue", 
                                             "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "Gold"
), X2022.08.01 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.02 = c(0, 0, 0, 
                                                      0, 0, 0), X2022.08.03 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.04 = c(10, 
                                                                                                                   10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.05 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.08 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.09 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.10 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.12 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.16 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.18 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.22 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.24 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.26 = c(10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           10, 10, 10, 10, 10), X2022.08.29 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.30 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2022.08.31 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Calling a a "merge" may be misleading people. In R parlance it's a sub-assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the column names of the source as indices on both sides of the assignment, you can get replacement with

```
test_1[ ,colnames(test_2)] <- test_2[ , colnames(test_2)]
```

```
test_1
      rn X2022.08.01 X2022.08.02 X2022.08.03 X2022.08.04 X2022.08.05 X2022.08.08 X2022.08.09
1   Blue          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
2   Pink          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
3    Red          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
4 Yellow          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
5  Green          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
6   Gold          10           0          10          10          10           0           0
  X2022.08.10 X2022.08.11 X2022.08.12 X2022.08.15 X2022.08.16 X2022.08.17 X2022.08.18 X2022.08.19
1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
3           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
4           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
5           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
6           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
  X2022.08.22 X2022.08.23 X2022.08.24 X2022.08.25 X2022.08.26 X2022.08.29 X2022.08.30 X2022.08.31
1           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
2           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
3           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
4           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
5           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
6           0           0           0           0          10           0           0           0
```

I doubt there could be a more simple method.. It could even work with a more limited number of rows as long as the indices area proper subset of the column and row names of the target matrix or dataframe. Note: I'm not understanding the issue with NA's. There were not NA's in either structure.